# Skew element horizontally but just right side

Tags: html, css

i want to have design as exactly below by help of HTML 5 and CSS 3. Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppz4L/) how i do it.

[image]

Here is the example codes

```
<div class="header">Akşam Sizin İçin Önerdiklerimiz
    <div class="skew"></div>
</div>
<div class="line"></div>

.header {
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #6b6a69;
    position: relative;
}
.skew {
    position: absolute;
    -moz-transform: skewX(45deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(45deg);
    -o-transform: skewX(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
    transform: skewX(45deg);
    right: -14px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 0;
    background: inherit;
    z-index: -1;
}
.line {
    height: 11px;
    background-color: #6b6a69;
    margin-top: -7px;
}
```

As you have seen that i used 3 html element to build this. What i want to achieve is to give a gradient background-color for whole that design. But there are 3 different elements so i can only apply gradient for each element separately and that wouldn't look as i want.

So i am trying to achieve that design by only 1 element via CSS 3 features like transformations.
At least skewing only right side as in the picture via removing div.skew element would be an improvement for me.

If it is possible to do that so how can i do that ?

Edit: Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ppz4L/2/) how it looks when i apply gradient so that is why i want to simply remove extra elements for applying gradient to whole design.

Comment: At least we have a way to apply the gradient to the whole shape but I don't think it uses just 1 element (without using pseudo-elements).

Comment: @KingKing we have a way to apply gradient to whole shape ? That means we can do this without having to reduce element number to 1 ?

Comment: of course, it is even easier (need just 1 element and its pseudo-element) if the parent background is just solid (such as in your case it's the white background), otherwise (image or gradient background), we have to use more elements.

Comment: Can you place a triangle that matches the background over the corner of a rectangle with the gradient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be an easier way to do it: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/aDoFc

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.header {
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    background-color: #6b6a69;
    position: relative;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(180,187,193,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(180,187,193,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(180,187,193,1) 100%); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(180,187,193,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(180,187,193,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(180,187,193,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    overflow: hidden;
}

span {position: relative; display: inline-block; padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;}
span:after {
    content: " ";
    width: 2000px;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 20px solid white;
    border-right: 0 solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <span>Akşam Sizin İçin Önerdiklerimiz</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks great. I thought :before and :after is exactly will be same as extra markup.  Thanks

Comment: It has more trick than :after and:before. I will check the example at pc better

Comment: You are CSS master, i hadn't thought it was possible to do this :)